# Tridion API call to get Xml containing Structure group and Page nodes with some sort of hierarchical relation

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am looking for an Tridion API call to get the XML containing all the structure groups and the pages beneath it with some sort of hierarchical relation. As of now I could not find such API call in the SDL Tridion documentation. Currently we are using below API call to get the list of structure groups RAW XML:

```
 Filter filter = new Filter();
 filter.Conditions["ItemType"] = 4;       // Only structure groups
 filter.Conditions["Recursive"] = true;
 XmlElement structureGroupList = page.ContextRepository.GetListOrganizationalItems(filter);
```

Then we are iterating through each structure group to get the XML containing the Pages node beneath the repective structuregroup.

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilter pageItemFilter = null;
pageItemFilter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(this.session);
pageItemFilter.ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Page };
pageItemFilter.Recursive = false;
XmlElement pageElements = structureGroup.GetListItems(pageItemFilter);
```

As the number of structure groups grows, the number of Tridion API calls are growing to fetch respective pages in it. This is causing performance issues at DB server end where the CPU is spiking to 50%.

Is there a single API call that can get the structure group and Pages with some sort of relation so that we can easily arrange them hierarchically with a single API call.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `IncludeRelativeWebDavUrlColumn` property of a filter to true to get some additional info

Comment: I tried that option, however it seems to be not providing solution. With the addition of above property, I could see URL attribute in tcm:Item nodes and this attribute is holding the name of the structure group or page. It is not holding the webdav URL or any additional information that I could use to arrange in hierarchy.

Comment: It's the relative path. It's relative to the structure group you are taeing list on. You can build WebDAV urls yourself if you know url of the sg you are taking list on and this property